# How can I apply the packaging for libvirt to build a package out of a git version?

Tags: virtualization, deb, packaging, git

I've been trying to work on [a patch to libvirt to enable Ceph/RBD storage volumes](https://github.com/Azendale/libvirt).

I would like to test my code now. I would like to do this as a package (or even a Launchpad PPA), so that I can cleanly remove it.

Obviously, someone has already done the work to get libvirt packaged for Ubuntu and Debian.

How can I take a git branch and build it into a package using the packaging the official Ubuntu package uses?

Bonus points if we can get something like the output of

```
git describe --abbrev=7 --always --tags
```

as the version, so I can end up with both the version (4.0.0) and the git tag (gfd7cb8c) in a version number such that newer versions actually look new to apt.

Comment: Have you gone through https://wiki.debian.org/PackagingWithGit?

Comment: @muru I've read it, but am a bit overwhelmed. Hence wanting to just use the already done packaging instead of trying to figure it all out from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use packaging files from the distribution (Ubuntu/Debian).

1. Create a source archive from your repository, and rename it correctly.

   ```
   <packagename>_<version>.orig.tar.gz
   ```

   The root folder inside the archive should be `<packagename>-<version>` which contain the whole source tree.

   Then extract it.
2. Download Debian packaging file `.debian.tar.zx` from:

   https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libvirt-bin

   Extract it and put `debian` folder inside `<packagename>-<version>` folder from the previous step.
3. Open terminal in `<packagename>-<version>` folder then build Debian source package.

   ```
   # if needed
   dch
   debuild clean
   # build source package only
   debuild -S
   ```
4. Upload it to PPA that will build binary packages for you.